# Symfony2 not save SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME in session

Tags: symfony, session-variables, session-cookies, symfony-2.3

I want obtain the last_username saved in session to use it in login form, but $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME) always is null

This is my code:

Config.yml

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  %locale%
    trusted_proxies: ['127.0.0.1']
    session:
      cookie_lifetime: 31536000
    fragments:       ~
```

Login action:

```
  public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        ld( $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME));

        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return array(
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error
        );
    }
```

When is the error?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: SecurityContext has no constants defined (http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html)
What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry but securityContext implements SecurityContextInterface and it has this constants: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContextInterface.html

Comment: Is it null when an invalid set of credentials is used? I noticed a similar problem, but mine is not null when I use an invalid set of credentials. However, logging in with XHR or using legit credentials results in null.

Comment: @MarcMoralesValldepérez Were you able to solve this issue??